# Excel VBA loops with columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Looking to loop using columns, relatively new to looping and have some existing code which is incredibly cumbersome:

```
Sub AdvanceWeek2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Victor

    ' Week1
    Range("V24:V124").Copy
    Range("U24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("V134:V234").Copy
    Range("U134").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("V244:V334").Copy
    Range("U244").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Week2
    Range("W24:W124").Copy
    Range("V24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("W134:W234").Copy
    Range("V134").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("W244:W334").Copy
    Range("V244").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Week3
    Range("W24:W124").ClearContents
    Range("W134:W234").ClearContents
    Range("W244:W334").ClearContents

' Nick

    ' Week1
    Range("Z24:Z124").Copy
    Range("Y24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("Z134:Z234").Copy
    Range("Y134").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("Z244:Z334").Copy
    Range("Y244").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Week2
    Range("AA24:AA124").Copy
    Range("Z24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("AA134:AA234").Copy
    Range("Z134").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("AA244:AA334").Copy
    Range("Z244").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Week3
    Range("AA24:AA124").ClearContents
    Range("AA134:AA234").ClearContents
    Range("AA244:AA334").ClearContents
```

This then gets repeated for another 11 people, so you can see how cumbersome this gets. How would I go about automating this into a loop to shorten the code and make it easier to edit in the future if small changes needed to be made?

Comment: Would you mind posting picture of data and tell exactly what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Is Victor the first person? Looks to me like each person has 3 columns, Victor's are U V and W... X is missed out so perhaps this is a formulated total?  Anyway, look at the use of `.Cells(1,2)` Where 1 is the row and 2 is the column so that would be `.Range("B1")`... You can then have a loop for each person with a counter that increases by 4 each time and uses something like `.Range(Cells(24,n),Cells(124,n))  & .Range(Cells(134,n+2)` etc.

Comment: Also you should avoid copy and paste wherever possible, I appreciate that sometimes this is unavoidable. In this instance you can just set the values of the target range to match the desired range: `Range("U24:U124").Value = Range("V24:V124").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub AdvanceWeek2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim var1 As Long, var2 As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    var1 = 22 'for Column V
    var2 = 100 'random max number
    cnt = 13 'no of people
    For i = var1 To var2
        Range(Cells(24, i), Cells(124, i)).Copy Cells(24, i - 1)
        Range(Cells(134, i), Cells(234, i)).Copy Cells(134, i - 1)
        Range(Cells(244, i), Cells(334, i)).Copy Cells(244, i - 1)
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            Union(Range(Cells(24, i), Cells(124, i)), Range(Cells(134, i), Cells(234, i)), Range(Cells(244, i), Cells(334, i))).ClearContents
            i = i + 2
            cnt = cnt - 1
            If cnt = 0 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to start thinking in column numbers rather than column letters.
Column U is column 21 (U being the 21st letter in the alphabet).

You can reference `U24` by either using `Range("U24")` or `Cells(24,21)` (row 24, column 21).
You reference a range of cells by giving it the first and last cells in the range, so `Range(Cells(24,21),Cells(124,21))` will reference `U24:U124` and is the same as writing `Range("U24:U124")`.

Now for the looping bit.  You want to reference column 21 for Victor, column 25 for Nick, column 29 for the next person, etc.  So you'll increase this loop in steps of 4.  You also need to reference different columns in each of these loops - moving column 2 to column 1, column 3 to column 2 and clearing column 3.

This bit of code will show how the loop works by printing the values to the immediate window. It will return `21 0, 21 1, 25 0, 25 1, 29 0, 29 1`

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 21 To 29 Step 4
            For y = 0 To 1
                Debug.Print x; y
            Next y
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

These x and y values need to be used in your column references and seeing as you just want the values we can make one range of cells equal the other rather than copy/pastespecial.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 21 To 29 Step 4
            For y = 0 To 1
                .Range(.Cells(24, x + y), .Cells(124, x + y)).Value = .Range(.Cells(24, x + y + 1), .Cells(124, x + y + 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(134, x + y), .Cells(234, x + y)).Value = .Range(.Cells(134, x + y + 1), .Cells(234, x + y + 1)).Value
                .Range(.Cells(244, x + y), .Cells(334, x + y)).Value = .Range(.Cells(244, x + y + 1), .Cells(334, x + y + 1)).Value
            Next y
            .Range(.Cells(24, x + y), .Cells(124, x + y)).ClearContents
            .Range(.Cells(134, x + y), .Cells(234, x + y)).ClearContents
            .Range(.Cells(244, x + y), .Cells(334, x + y)).ClearContents
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Add a watch for the values of X & Y and step through the code using F8.  You'll see the values increase to reference the correct columns.

Note I've used the `With..End With` keywords.  This means that each range that starts with a `.` is referencing `Sheet1` of the workbook containing the code (`ThisWorkbook`).

**Edit:**
If you want to copy the cells (including formatting, formula, etc) then you can use:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 21 To 29 Step 4
            For y = 0 To 1
                .Range(.Cells(24, x + y + 1), .Cells(124, x + y + 1)).Copy Destination:=.Range(.Cells(24, x + y), .Cells(124, x + y))
                .Range(.Cells(134, x + y + 1), .Cells(234, x + y + 1)).Copy Destination:=.Range(.Cells(134, x + y), .Cells(234, x + y))
                .Range(.Cells(244, x + y + 1), .Cells(334, x + y + 1)).Copy Destination:=.Range(.Cells(244, x + y), .Cells(334, x + y))
            Next y
            Union(.Range(.Cells(24, x + y), .Cells(124, x + y)), _
                  .Range(.Cells(134, x + y), .Cells(234, x + y)), _
                  .Range(.Cells(244, x + y), .Cells(334, x + y))).ClearContents
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

(that union line could be used in the first example as well).

Answer (score 0):

From your code it doesn't look like the username is important, just the fact there are 12 users.

12 users, 3 weeks...

A quick and minimal code approach is to:

Loop through your code 12 times (once for each user).
Have a nested loop for the 3 weeks per user, applying an offset to a base (or starting) column for each copy and paste operation.

```
Sub AdvanceWeek2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim intLoopUser As Integer
Dim intLoopWeek As Integer

Dim rngBase As Range

Set rngBase = ActiveSheet.Range("V24:V124")

For intLoopUser = 0 To 35 Step 3 '12 Users, change the Step as required, looked like 3 from your code, maybe 4

    For intLoopWeek = 0 To 2 '3 weeks

        Select Case intLoopWeek
        Case 0 'Week 1
            rngBase.Offset(0, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(0, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
            rngBase.Offset(110, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(110, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
            rngBase.Offset(210, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(210, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
        Case 1 'Week 2
            rngBase.Offset(0, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(0, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
            rngBase.Offset(110, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(110, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
            rngBase.Offset(210, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).Value = rngBase.Offset(210, intLoopUser + intLoopWeek).Value
        Case 2 'Week 3
            rngBase.Offset(0, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).ClearContents
            rngBase.Offset(110, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).ClearContents
            rngBase.Offset(210, (intLoopUser + intLoopWeek) - 1).ClearContents

       End Select

    Next intLoopWeek

Next intLoopUser

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```